# Angular ui-router $state.go how to only refresh child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having a problem on ui-router, I have 2 states, one is called "lbe", the other is "main", which is a child state of "lbe". In the application, there is a button, what I'm trying to do is just refresh the child state, which is "main", and all views under the parent state "lbe" will not be reloaded.

Here is some sample code:

"lbe" state:

```
.state('lbe', {
    abstract: true,
    reloadOnSearch: false,
    url: '/?customerId&routeId&startMp&endMp&currentLayers',
    onEnter: function(){
      //debugger;
    },
    params: {
      customerId: '1',
      routeId: '1333',
      startMp: '380',
      endMp: null,
      currentLayers: []
    },
    resolve: appResolverProvider.lbe,
    views: {
       //.....
    }
  });
```

"main" state:

```
.state('main', {
    parent: 'lbe',
    url: 'lbe',
    onEnter: function($rootScope, $stateParams){
      $rootScope.$broadcast('foo', $stateParams);
      //debugger;
    },
    views: {
      //...
    }
 });
```

$state.go:

```
 $state.go('main', {
     routeId: routeID,
     startMp: startMP,
     endMp: endMP,
     currentLayers: commonService.getLayerParams(lrsFeatureClassSymbologySqs)
 });
```

The current issue is when $state.go is triggered, both "lbe" and "main" are reloaded, however, I only want to reload "main".

Thanks

**Edit:**

Here is the html code:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="getRoutelogData(main.routeID, main.startMP, main.endMP)">Go</button>
```

"getRouteLog" function:

```
 $scope.getRoutelogData = function(routeID, startMP, endMP) {
                $state.go('main', {
                    routeId: routeID,
                    startMp: startMP,
                    endMp: endMP,
                    currentLayers: commonService.getLayerParams(lrsFeatureClassSymbologySqs)
                });


    };
```

Comment: can you share plase your html code?

Comment: thanks, oware, just updated the question.